# Is it possible to disable image resize option in crop box?

Tags: angular

Currently, I'm using angular and to crop ngx-image-cropper is used. I want to disable the image resizing option inside the crop box. I have not found any attributes to disable resizer.

Thank in advance.

Comment: You can not achieve this without chnage source code. Are u find with this? By looking at source code, its not very large code. You can import the library directly as source and use the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following attributes

```
resizeToWidth=0 
resizeToHeight=0
```